# Unable to ping host from guest

Tags: laptop, vmware-workstation

I installed Linux Redhat 6.3 on VMware workstation 9 as a guest to Windows 7 hosts, but unable to ping the guest from the host, and unable to ping the pc name from the guest.

I configured bridge (VMnet0) and additional adapter host-only (VMnet1)

```
C:\Users\pete>ipconfig/all
Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : pete-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : woh.rr.com
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) WiMAX 6150
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 64-D4-DA-67-42-BE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-25-C2-93-95-41
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-25-C2-93-95-41
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : woh.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : DC-0E-A1-3C-C9-1A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3d74:187a:5703:57d8%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 174.102.33.43(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, March 26, 2013 10:25:08 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, March 26, 2013 9:37:43 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 174.102.32.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.83.192.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 349965985
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-96-B1-6F-40-25-C2-93-95-40
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.61
                                       209.18.47.62
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 6150
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-25-C2-93-95-40
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::81e4:701b:d4d2:d169%27(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.15(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.10
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318787670
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-96-B1-6F-40-25-C2-93-95-40
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.10
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b504:e2ee:bbb1:509e%28(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.10
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335564886
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-96-B1-6F-40-25-C2-93-95-40
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.10
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:953c:3c1c:20ee:5199:ded4(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c1c:20ee:5199:ded4%18(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{8DE8E8F0-3DF1-494A-8B37-9966ADA9A8CF}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : woh.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:ae66:212b::ae66:212b(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.61
                                       209.18.47.62
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{B4FB8A15-7A4D-4E92-90FD-03EB5A05667C}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{D957AFA7-530F-476B-84C9-D68C56429B41}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{991627D3-A91F-404C-A057-FBC7E38FF034}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.woh.rr.com:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : woh.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{7199B5CC-4176-491A-A1D2-93959EB270EF}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{ACEECC55-C0BA-4128-A393-5A024474833E}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Edit your post to include, in a separate code block, the output from 'ifconfig' as root on the guest. Without knowing that side of what's going on, there's no way to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: Are you trying to ping by name or by IP?  It sounds as if you're trying to do it by name, which likely won't work unless you're running a DNS server as well?

Comment: @ernie, my thoughts exactly. Try pinging by IP 172.xx.xx.xx it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I've done this many time for development testing. Sometimes, firewall can cause problems too. Try to turn it off and see if it works. If you want to ping by name, set domain in your hosts file. BTW, I'm using NAT

```
<RHEL IP ADDRESS>     domain.local.dev
```

Good luck

Comment: Just want to add that he's unable to ping by PC Name because Linux don't work with NetBIOS names and therefore it doesn't know what to ping. Adding to hosts file would work as a workaround but if user changes pc name he'd need to edit hosts file again. Most of the time it's very acceptable way :)